# javascript nested object from array Unexpected token [

Tags: javascript

I do not understand why I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` when I do the following:

```
    var thisarray = ["one","two","three"]
    var thisobj = {
                     thisarray[0] : {thisarray[1] : thisarray[2]}
                  }
```

There is a similar syntax error that I get from trying this:

```
$scope.find_settings.find = {$scope.query_main_type:findarray}
```

here the unexpected token is `.`. Doesn't javascript resolve the expressions when creating objects or what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

Try either

```js
var thisarray = ["one", "two", "three"]
var thisobj = {
  [thisarray[0]]: {
    [thisarray[1]]: thisarray[2]
  }
}

// Don't use document.write in prod/dev use console.log instead
document.write(JSON.stringify(thisobj));
```

Or

```js
var thisarray = ["one", "two", "three"]
var thisobj = {};
var thisobj1 = {};

thisobj1[thisarray[1]] = thisarray[2];
thisobj[thisarray[0]] = thisobj1;

document.write(JSON.stringify(thisobj));
```